# How to use specific dependency of design support for Tablayout?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-tablayout

I am using `TabLayout` in my application I need to add dependency into my app module like:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
```

But when I am using whole design support I need to enable multidex because there are lot of other dependency. When earlier I use google play service support then I used this for specific support like:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
```

Here I want to use specific dependency only for `TabLayout`. Any help will be heighly appreciable.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no any dependency as you want

Answer (score 0):

There is just one dependency for the whole design library. Dependency for just `TabLayout` is not provided.

Comment: i have lot of dependencies and i have to enable multidex so it takes a lot of time to run the entire app.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no individual dependency inside design repo.

Comment: Sorry, did not know, new kid around the block sir :(   want me to delete this?

Comment: @dev.mi Actually, it looks like this is the correct answer for this question.

Comment: Yes it actually is the correct answer. There is no existing dependency which allows what he wants. That is unless he clones the class from some source and adds it as a library with resources.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no separate dependency only for Tablayout. If you are using any component in the material design library, you have to add the whole dependency.refer [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)